# problem with connecting to mssql from php script

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to my database with this address: http://localhost:8989/latihanPHP/todolist.php
but my browser keeps loading and is too long to respond, it didn't say anything.

I have 2 localhost in my computer:

1. localhost
2. localhost:8989

Could it be the problem?

This is my code:

```
$servername = "localhost:8989";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: No you don't have 2 `localhost` on your computer. `localhost` is just an alias of your local ip address `127.0.0.1`. You might however have multiple applications running on different ports like `8989` or `80`. Now it seems that port `8989` is used for your web server not the database. Maybe you want to check again what's your database port.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of using localhost.

So you should try to use this:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1:8989";
```

This is from PHP documentation:

> "The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use
>   of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection
>   using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead."

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

I hope this helps.